# How to install phpmyadmin to mysql instance

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-sql

I have created mysql instance from google cloud,
I will like to use database via phpmyadmin
to create tables, import from old sql.

Can I install phpmyadmin under deployed mysql google cloud,
Or I have to have phpmyadmin or third party software which I can install to my computer to access sql created under google cloud.

Comment: if the db allows remote connections to it via its IP, as I imagine it probably must, if it's a cloud DB, then you can install phpmyadmin anywhere you like, doesn't need to be in the same machine. Equally you can probably connect via MySQL workbench, or any other MySQL client software. Check the docs from google to see if you have to whitelist the locations from which connections can be made, or if there are fees charged for external access, etc etc.

Comment: thanks for advice. workbench seems like working but google cloud sql is stubborn to give access to remote connection. working on it though...

Comment: if workbench is working ok connecting to the remote SQL then your remote connection setup is already working, surely?

Comment: it is unbelive but today nothing want to work. I tried oth PCs to install workbench even I install requirement dot net etc. giving weird problems. so redirect to workbench alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can run PHPMyAdmin on Google App Engine and have it connect to your Google Cloud SQL instance. There is a tutorial for doing this at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine